# How to values in MySQL with bash script

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I am trying to create a bash script for entering values in to a mySQL database. The ultimate goal is to gather data about hard drives with smartmontools, but I am getting so many errors I decided to break it down and start very simple. I am a total noob at bash / mySQL. My test database now only contains a table with USER and DATE.
This is my bash script:

```
USR=$USER
DATE=$(date +%y%m%d)
mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -ppw -Dtest<<EOF INSERT INTO testtbl (USER, DATE) VALUES('$USR', $DATE);
EOF
exit
```

This is the error message I get:

```
./ysmartmon: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./ysmartmon: line 4: `mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -ppw -Dtest<<EOF INSERT INTO testtbl (USER, DATE) VALUES('$USR', $DATE);'
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is it this ` I need to get rid off? But how do I do that?

Comment: You can execute SQL statements by writing a series of commands into a file like  `mysql.sql` like this:                                                                        `echo insert into database.testtbl....    >> mysql.sql`  then just execute  `mysql -uuser -ppw -hlocalhost mysql.sql`

Comment: Also you might have to escape some of the characters  like  `( ) [ ] $ ! > < &`  by adding a `\ `  before them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the line after `<< EOF`, like this:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -ppw -Dtest << EOF
INSERT INTO testtbl (USER, DATE) VALUES('$USR', $DATE);
EOF
```

This `<< EOF` construct is called a *here-document*,
you can read more about it in `man bash`.
To search for this in `man bash`,
type `/here-doc` and press Enter.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also added the spaces before and after <<.  Now I can finally continue with the next step.